# Replace id to original_id in mongo using python

Tags: mongodb, python-3.6

***I Tried this code but it doesn't work***
***can anyone please help me in this by giving me such code***

```
query = {"_id" : ObjectId("5de8b6168b088f5c6fcde3b0")}
replacement = {"original_id" : ObjectId("5de8b52ce34f0a6b7896187f")}

result = col.replace_one(query, replacement)

print(result)
```

Comment: what are you trying to do here ? can you edit this question with original doc & updated doc !!

Comment: I want to replace _id to original_id with values

def get_all():
    users = mongo.db.bid_cdc
    print(users)
    query = {"_id" : ObjectId("5de8b6168b088f5c6fcde3b0")}
    replacement = {"original_id" : ObjectId("5de8b52ce34f0a6b7896187f")}
    doc = users.find_one(query)
    doc._id = replacement
    users.insert(doc)
    users.remove(query)
    print(users)
    return json.dumps(users,cls=JSONEncoder)